# How can I get the key,value from a variable of type List<Map<String,dynamic>>?

Tags: list, dictionary, dart, casting

In dart I query a database and get a return of type `List<Map<String,dynamic>>` like this:

```
List<Map<String,dynamic>> result =await DatabaseHelper.instance.queryForDate(2);
```

I then printed like this:

```
print(result.toString());
```

and got a map like this:

```
{_id: 2, user: U8KCKeriKo2, date: 2021-04-30}
```

Then I tried to get the user like this:

```
print(result['user'].toString() );
```

which produces the message:

```
The argument of type string can't be assigned to the parameter type int
```

Tried accessing the user with something like...

```
  print(result[1].toString() );
```

This produces the error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 2
```

How can I get the key, value from a variable of type  `List<Map<String,dynamic>>`?

Comment: As clearly indicated by the declaration from the first line, `result` is a `List`, not a `Map`.  Its `operator []` accepts only integers.  To access the `'user'` entry for the i-th `Map`, you would need to use `result[i]['user']`.  Note that `List`s are indexed from 0.  When you attempted `result[1]` (and the error message indicates that you actually attempted to use `result[2]`), the `List` had only one element, so `result[1]` (and `result[2]`) would be out of bounds.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I spent the better of two days researching casting and converting methods... what a novice I am!